# Is it possible to add tensors of different sizes together in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I have an image gradient of size `(3, 224, 224)` and a patch of `(1, 768)`. is it possible to add this gradient to the patch to get a size of the patch `(1, 768)`?

Forgive my inquisitiveness. I know pytorch too utilizes broadcasting and I am not sure if I will able to do so with two different tensors in way similar to the line below:

```
torch.add(a, b)
```

For example:
[image]

The end product would be the same patch on the left with the gradient of an entire image on the right added to it. My understanding is that it’s not possible, but knowledge isn’t bounded.

Comment: What would the shape of your desired output look like?

Comment: What does 768 represent for the patch? Is `(1, 768)` the shape of the flattened patch?

Comment: @flawr, my desired output too would be `(1, 768)`

Comment: @Ivan `768` represents `(3, 16, 16)`

Comment: Could you provide an example with the desired output?

Comment: @Ivan, I have update the question to include a pictorial representation

Comment: *the gradient of an entire image on the right added to it*, the gradient of which quantity with respect to what? Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out to do it myself. I divided the image gradient (right) into `16 x 16` patches, created a loop that adds each patch to the original image patch (left). This way, I was able to add a `224 x 22`4 image gradient into a `16 x 16` patch. I just wanted to see what would happen if I do such

Answer (score 2):

No. Whether two tensors are broadcastable is defined by the following [rules](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html#general-semantics):

- Each tensor has at least one dimension.
- When iterating over the dimension sizes, starting at the trailing dimension, the dimension sizes must either be equal, one of them is 1, or one of them does not exist.

Because the second bullet doesn't hold in your example (i.e., `768 != 224`, `1 not in {224, 768}`), you can't broadcast the add. If you have some meaningful way to reshape your gradients, you might be able to.